# Interpreting plot of residuals vs. fitted values from Poisson regression

Tags: r, self-study, generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression

I am trying to fit data with a GLM (poisson regression) in R.  When I plotted the residuals vs the fitted values, the plot created multiple (almost linear with a slight concave curve) "lines".  What does this mean?

```
library(faraway)
modl <- glm(doctorco ~ sex + age + agesq + income + levyplus + freepoor + 
            freerepa + illness + actdays + hscore + chcond1 + chcond2,
            family=poisson, data=dvisits)
plot(modl)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know if you can upload the plot (sometimes newcomers can't), but if not, could you at least add some data & R code to your question so people can evaluate it?

Comment: Jocelyn, I've updated your post with information you put in a comment. I also tagged this as `homework` since you talked about an assignment.

Comment: try plot(jitter(mod1)) to see if the graph is a bit more readable.  Why don't you define residuals for us and give us your best guess as interpreting the graph yourself.

Comment: Also, look up the poisson distribution and then graph your outcome variable.  plot(doctorco) - it should be strictly positive.

Comment: From the question, I'm going to assume that you understand the Poisson distribution & Pois reg, and what a plot of residuals vs fitted values tells you (update if that's wrong), thus you are just wondering about the odd appearance of the points in the plot. B/c this is homework, we don't quite answer as our general policy, but provide hints. I notice that you have a *lot* of covariates, I wonder if you have 1 continuous & many binary covariates.

Comment: Yes, I am wondering about the appearance of the points.  There is a mix of binary and continuous. I used backwards elimination to make a simpler model.  The simplier model also has binary and continuous variables, and the plot looks similar.

Comment: Two followups from gung's comment. First, try `table(dvisits$doctorco)`. What do the 10 curved lines on your plot correspond to, in this table? Also, with in excess of 5000 observations, don't worry too much about fitting 13 regression coefficients.

Answer (score 34):

**This is the appearance you expect of such a plot when the dependent variable is discrete.**

Each curvilinear trace of points on the plot corresponds to a fixed value $k$ of the dependent variable $y$.  Every case where $y=k$ has a prediction $\hat{y}$; its residual--by definition--equals $k-\hat{y}$.  The plot of $k-\hat{y}$ versus $\hat{y}$ is obviously a line with slope $-1$.  In Poisson regression, the x-axis is shown on a log scale: it is $\log(\hat{y})$.  The curves now bend down exponentially.  As $k$ varies, these curves rise by integral amounts.  Exponentiating them gives a set of quasi-parallel curves.  (To prove this, the plot will be explicitly constructed below, separately coloring the points by the values of $y$.)

**We can reproduce the plot in question** quite closely by means of a similar but arbitrary model (using small random coefficients):

```
# Create random data for a random model.
set.seed(17)
n <- 2^12                       # Number of cases
k <- 12                         # Number of variables
beta = rnorm(k, sd=0.2)         # Model coefficients
x <- matrix(rnorm(n*k), ncol=k) # Independent values
y <- rpois(n, lambda=exp(-0.5 + x %*% beta + 0.1*rnorm(n)))

# Wrap the data into a data frame, create a formula, and run the model.
df <- data.frame(cbind(y,x))    
s.formula <- apply(matrix(1:k, nrow=1), 1, function(i) paste("V", i+1, sep=""))
s.formula <- paste("y ~", paste(s.formula, collapse="+"))
modl <- glm(as.formula(s.formula), family=poisson, data=df)

# Construct a residual vs. prediction plot.
b <- coefficients(modl)
y.hat <- x %*% b[-1] + b[1]     # *Logs* of the predicted values
y.res <- y - exp(y.hat)         # Residuals
colors <- 1:(max(y)+1)          # One color for each possible value of y
plot(y.hat, y.res, col=colors[y+1], main="Residuals v. Fitted")
```

[image: Residuals vs. fitted]

Comment: (+1) The color goes a long way in showing what is happening.

Comment: So is the above plot concerning? Texts (Statistical Modeling for Biomedical Researchers: A Simple Introduction to the Analysis of Complex Data, Dupont, 2002, p. 316, e.g.) indicate the fitted vs. residual plot should be centered about the zero residual line, and either fan (if raw residuals) or not (if deviance, e.g.). With a limited range of counts in the outcome variable, you get these bands, and, as in the above plot, they're not centered about the line at y = 0. How do we know the OP's residual plot (or the example plot made in this answer) indicates the model is fitting the data well?

Comment: @Meg That advice doesn't directly apply to residuals of a GLM.  Note that the model used to illustrate this answer is known to be correct because it's the one used to generate the data.

Comment: 1/2: Thanks @whuber. I understand for this answer the model is known to be correct since the data were simulated from a given distribution, but in practice it's unknown (as in the OP's post). Also, what I wrote about residuals *does* apply to POI regression (not all GLMs, no, but this one) - the reference I gave was discussing POI regression specifically. I've only seen texts show standardized POI residuals (Pearson or deviance, e.g.) centered about y = 0, so I'm not sure what I should be looking for, because for this model (which is obviously correct), the plot looks nothing like that.

Comment: 2/2: Do you have a go-to reference that discusses POI residuals more thoroughly by any chance?

Comment: @Meg Hosmer & Lemeshow, *Applied Logistic Regression,* include a section on diagnostic plots.

Comment: @whuber - thanks, but I don't see any discussion of Poisson regression in this text.

Comment: This code does not work since `s.formula` is called before it is defined.

Comment: @Pierre Thank you for pointing that out.  That was the result of a last-minute change in line 11, where the lhs should have read `s.formula` instead of `vars`.  I have fixed it in the post.

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes stripes like these in residual plots represent points with (almost) identical observed values that get different predictions. Look at your target values: how many unique values are they? If my suggestion is correct there should be 9 unique values in your training data set.

Comment: +1.  (There's actually a tenth one represented as a single point near the upper right corner.)  The values, of course, are $0, 1, \ldots, 9$.

Answer (score -3):

This pattern is characteristic of an incorrect match of the family and/or link. If you have overdispersed data then perhaps you should consider the negative binomial (count) or gamma (continuous) distributions. Also you should be plotting your residuals against the transformed linear predictor, not the predictors when using generalized linear models. To transform the Poisson predictor you need to take 2 times the square root of the linear predictor and plot your residuals against that. The residuals further more should not be exclusively pearson residuals, try deviance residuals and studentized resids.

Comment: Why 2 times the square root, when the canonical link of the poisson family in a glm is log?  Shouldn't it be exp() of the linear predictor?  But I don't see what the problem is with plotting residuals against the linear predictor itself, which I think is what is being done here - perhaps you could expand on that.

Comment: Would you mind explaining just what aspect of the "pattern" is drawing your attention to a possible model mis-specification, Ryan? It seems to be a subtle thing, but is potentially an important insight.