# Meaning of a Residual plot that looks like composition of sawtooth waves

Tags: regression, residuals

I'm working on a prototype that reads a fixed mass in a loadcell through an 24 bit ADC using a MCU; the device undergoes high temperature amplitudes, therefore the mass readings drift (because of the analog electronics) even though the mass doesn't physically change (it's always 1260 g). I`ve tested the device in a chamber that undergoes cyclic temperature changes. When I did linear regression on the dataset of the test (mass (in grams) vs temperature (in Celsius)), I got a high R^2 but the residual plot looks really weird...

What's the meaning of this? Is it a consequence of the quantization error of the ADC?[image]

the Y axis is the mass residue in grams; the X axis is the (temperature*10) in Celsius, e.g. x=100 <=> 10°C

UPDATE: I've added transparency to the plot, it can be verified that most the parallel left-most line has more opacity (because most of the temperature cycles happened at that temperature, hence more observations). Also, by plotting the histogram we can verify that indeed there are 6 distinctive larger groups plus a small group (the opaque blue plot has 6 lines and one small dot near the -12 g label, therefore 7 groups I suppose)

[image: Residuals plot with transparency]

[image: Histogram]

Comment: Do you have six different masses?

Comment: @mdewey No, but I could find some other masses to test

Comment: @mdewey, Do you mean, if I used 6 different masses on the test or if I have 6 masses at my disposal to test? I only used a single mass on the test, the readings change because the temperature affects the analog electronics.

Comment: This is duplicate, a question that has been posted many times. e.g. see here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235449/help-interpreting-residuals-vs-fit-graph-multiple-regression ... naturally that's also a duplicate, but I picked that one because it's particularly clear that it's the same problem there. If you search for descriptions like *regression diagonal lines  residual* and similar variations, you turn up relevant hits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition

residual $=$ observed response $-$ fitted response

means that in a plot of residual (y axis) versus fitted (x axis) points for each distinct observed response plot on a line with intercept that value and gradient $-1$. Hence the various distinct observed values plot as a series of parallel lines. That is visible on your plot.

As @mdewey comments, it appears that you have just 6 distinct observed values, which should be easy to check directly.

Some people say unique, not distinct. Similarly some people say predicted, not fitted

Comment: Thanks for the interpretation, I've decided to add transparency to the residuals plot. I could verify that the left-most parallel line had greater opacity than the other lines, i.e. most of the temperature cycles concentrated around -4°C to +2°C. Then I plotted the histogram, breaking the binning into 10g intervals starting from 1200 to 1290, only 6 big groups of masses could be observed.

Comment: But does this great clustering around only 6 groups means my model is broken? (i.e. non-linear)

Comment: I wouldn't say that this alone breaks your model. In principle it's **always** true that a residual vs fitted plot is a series of parallel lines, but that's not a source of worry if there are many of it.