# Odd looking residual plot - not sure what transform to use if any

Tags: residuals, count-data

[image: Residuals fitted plot]

I am concerned about the residual plot shown. The (count) data are over-dispersed, with about 40% 0s, median is 2, maximum is 300 or so.

I am not sure what how to proceed with this - it is not exactly like any of the classic examples that are on various teaching websites, and I have not yet found a transformation that makes the plot look "well-behaved".

Comment: what model are these residuals coming from?

Comment: @ChristophHanck the command used first is: model<-lm(OverllTot0 ~ EurAdmix + Sex + DisDurMonths + BMI + Group + SmokingStatus + MedUse, data=covfiledt), then
plot(predict(model),residuals(model),xlab="Fitted",ylab="Residuals")

Comment: have you tried a count data model if your data is count data?

Comment: yes, 
library(MASS)
model<-glm.nb(OverllTot0~ EurAdmix + Sex + sqrt(DisDurMonths) + BMI + Group + SmokingStatus + MedUse, data=covfiledt)
returns something similar, except the flat line at the bottom is slightly curved. but overall it looks quite similar.

Comment: That almost straight line at the bottom must come from those almost 40% zeros, not much to do about that!

Comment: Closely related: [Interpreting plot of residuals vs. fitted values from Poisson regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25068). Another possibility (although likely not appropriate in this particular instance) is discussed at [How to model this odd-shaped distribution](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49443).