# Strong pattern on residual plot (simple linear regression in R)

Tags: r, regression, residuals

I am a novice in R, and fitting a linear model with lm().
Here is a summary of my linear model.

[image: summary of model]

Here are some assumption checking plots

[image: residual plot]
[image: normal qqplot]
[image: normal histogram]

The normal histogram and qqplot looks okay to me, but there are strong patterns appearing in the residual plot. Anybody have a clue
 why that might be happening? I logged my dependent variable because it
 was highly skewed and most of my independent variables are
 categorical. I have got only a few continuous variables. Thanks for
 reading my post!

Comment: It would be helpful if you drew the line y=x on your q-q plot. I do not think that it looks OK.

Comment: I believe this is answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25068 (as well as in several other threads on residuals in regression): your response is discrete and bounded below.  That is a strong indication that the model is inappropriate, because it does not account for this striking form of variation in the conditional distributions of the responses.