# Residuals still zero inflated after running zero-inflated poisson mixed effect model with glmmTMB

Tags: normal-distribution, residuals, poisson-regression, zero-inflation, glmmtmb

I am working with observational data which has a right skew in the dependent variable. This is a mixed effect model with a poisson distribution as based on discrete data. After finding the residuals from the model were not normal, and sjstats function overfit(model) highlighted zero-inflation to be an issue I ran the model in glmmTMB:

```
fit_zipoisson <- glmmTMB(freq~(B1 + B2)+(1|ref),data=da, ziformula=~1,
    family=poisson())
```

But running the model diagnostics afterwards still reveal a non-normal distribution and a zero-inflation.

```
zero_count(fit_zipoisson)

Zero-Count overfitting

Observed zero-counts: 295
Predicted zero-counts: 100
                 Ratio: 0.34

Model is underfitting zero-counts (probable zero-inflation).

Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  resid(fit_zipoisson)
W = 0.57262, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Does anyone have any advice on what to do next?

Comment: You have a poisson model, so why do you expect normal residuals? Besides, there is no no "normality assumption" in poisson regression. To test residuals, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25068/interpreting-plot-of-residuals-vs-fitted-values-from-poisson-regression and  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70558/diagnostic-plots-for-count-regression/248035#248035

Answer (score 3):

A better way to check the fit of such a model would be the simulated scaled residuals of the [**DHARMa**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=DHARMa) package. In addition, note that the `glmmTMB()` fits the model using the Laplace approximation which may not be optimal do discrete data. As an alternative you may also try the [**GLMMadaptive**](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/) package that fits the same model using the adaptive Gaussian quadrature. You can also find an example of testing the goodness-of-fit [here](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Goodness_of_Fit.html).