# Striped residuals from Generalized Mixed Model

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme

Related Q: [Interpreting plot of residuals vs. fitted values from Poisson regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25068/interpreting-plot-of-residuals-vs-fitted-values-from-poisson-regression)

I have had "stripey" residuals from a Generalized Mixed Model (with gamma distribution) but am still confused from the linked discussion **whether they are acceptable or not**. I know why I am seeing them-- my outcome variable has only 10 possible values-- and the distribution of values is non-normal, but am not sure what can & should be done to better model this data.

[image]

My model:

```
glmer(y ~ x + sex + age + source + x:sex + x:source + x:sex:source + (1 | ID), 
      data = d,
      family = Gamma(link=identity),
               control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa" , 
                                      optCtrl = list(maxfun= 10000)),
      nAGQ = 1)
```

...where **y** is score on a questionnaire (min-max: 1-11), **ID** are participants,  **source** is a binary within-person repeated measure and **x** is a continuous variable. I chose to use a Gamma distribution due to positive skew in the outcome & an identity link function in order to facilitate interpretation of estimates in terms of the original outcome units.

*Must* I declare the outcome as ordinal?
And if so, does that mean I must switch packages e.g. MCMCglmm (ordinal GLMM)?