Residual plot has pattern when all predictors included, less of a pattern when only weak predictor included
I saw something unexpected in the residual plots of my regression analysis: when I plot the residuals vs. the fitted values for the full model with multiple predictors (R squared = 0.24), I get a plot that seems to have a downward slanted pattern.


I don't have more predictors to add that could have been left out, so out of curiosity I started leaving predictors out to see what would happen, and the pattern always looked similar except for a case where only one predictor was left which on its own isn't significant, with an R squared of only 0.001. For this regression, the residual plot looks less problematic, but I would have expected the opposite because in this reduced model, a lot of predictors that have explanatory power are missing.


Does anyone have an explanation for this, and is the residual plot for the full model very problematic or fine? Does the downward trend tell me anything about what kind of variable is missing, e.g. how it is supposed to be correlated with the outcome?

Add a trend line (+ geom_smooth()) and I think you'll find there isn't much of a trend problem. You might want to fit a count model (Poisson/negative binomial) to these discrete data ...

I don't believe the title of your second plot, because it shows a clear upward trend.  What is it really?

@Ben Bolker Thank you that's helpful! I did think there's not really a trend, just the odd slant worried me, but I think it may be because of the nature of the discrete data like you suggest

@whuber It's the outcome variable on the y-axis and the predicted Y values on the x-axis - wouldn't I expect the upward trend? In the case of a perfect prediction, wouldn't the plot be a perfectly diagonal line?

Thank you for explaining.  When you fit that trend line in the second plot, what do you think the pattern of residuals ought to be?  Compare this to what amounts to the same question (for logistic regression) discussed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25068.

It's the discreteness of Y. You see it in the lines. The slant in the lines is caused by better predictions, but it is does not indicate any problem other than discreteness.
